# Referencing cell containing filepath for sub

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the following code to grab and resize a picture from file so I can print it out as part of a form.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert ("C:\Filepath\Example.jpg")
With ActiveSheet.Shapes(ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count)

.LockAspectRatio = True 'maintain aspect-ratio
.Top = Range("B2").Top
.Left = Range("B2:H2").Left
.Width = Range("B2:H2").Width 'same width of C3
End With
End Sub
```

My problem is I'm trying to get the code to reference a cell which contains the filepath for the photo to be imported. It only works currently if I type the filepath directly into the code. Could someone advise me how to do this please.

Say for example I want to insert a photo C:\Filepath\Example.jpg and I have typed this filepath (or ideally just the file name itself, but I'd settle for the full filepath for now) into cell A1 and want to use a command button to import the photo using the code above. Do I have to define A1 as a string or something? I haven't used excel for a year and alas my memory has forsaken me :(

Comment: Thank you djikay! Just seen your answer now, I lazily assumed I'd get an email notification of a reply! Code is working fine, I'll post the full text for a future searcher when I finalise it. Thanks again, I am most grateful.

Answer (score 1):

You can just get the contents of cell `A1` in the active sheet like this:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value ' or .Text
```

So, assuming the path to your picture is in cell A1 then, in your code, you'd replace:

```
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert ("C:\Filepath\Example.jpg")
```

with:

```
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value
```

*Note:* you don't need the parentheses.